# Some doubts about JavaScript plugin for Aptana Studio and Eclipse? What is the difference?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ide, aptana, aptana3

I am learning JavaScript and, coming from Java and PHP I am pretty confident with Eclipse and Aptana (an Eclipse version mainly dedicated for PHP and web development).

So I am using Aptana and I have the following doubt.

Reading a manual it speack about an Eclipse plugin named **JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT)** (this one: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/ )

So I think that this is compatible also with Aptana (because Aptana is a specific Eclipse version).

My doubt is: is it pre-installed in my Aptana installation? Or is it pre-installed something that give me the same behavior?

So I done: click on **Help ---> About Aptana Studio 3 ---> Installation Details ---> Plugin tab** and here I can see the list of all the installed plugin.

I can't see the **JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT)** but searching for JavaScript stuff I found the following 4 plugins:

- **Aptana JavaScript Editor**
- **Aptana JavaScript Formatter**
- **Rhino JavaScript Plugin**
- **V8 JavaScript Debug UI**

Is it the **JSTD** plugin or what? Or is it something similar dedicated for Aptana that give me the same behavior?

Another doubt is related to the last plugin found in the previous list (**V8 JavaScript Debug UI**). What is it? I know that I can debug a JavaScript script into my browser (using FireBug for example). Why I have a debugger into the IDE? What it is used for?

Tnx